# JBoss 7.4 JMS connectivity issue

Tags: jms, jboss7.x

We are migrating from JBoss 6.4 to JBoss 7.4. While deploying the war we are facing, "Required services that are not installed."

We checked the connection factor syntax for JBoss 7.4 and using as below in both `domain.xml` and `mule-config.xml`.

```
javaconnectionFactoryJndiName="java:/jms/ConnectionFactoryName"
```

Error while deploying war:

```
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [ "jboss.naming.context.java.jms.ConnectionFactoryName"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies"=> ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.warnamae.env.ConnectionFactoryName is missing"
```

Expecting successful JMS connection but results above issues.